# ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0 - Is there any way to snap a polygon / feature class to pixels within a Raster?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, clip, feature-class, pixel

I need to clip a raster to a specific area of interest, and a specific number of pixels.

Whilst I can manually draw my AOI feature class and get the right number of pixels, it generally contains a number of partial pixels, which causes issues with later analysis (image attached).

[image]Is there any way to draw a polygon that snaps to the pixels of a raster image, so that no partial pixels are present within the clipped raster?

I'm using a 10m resolution Sentinel-2 image, and trying to clip to a 16 x 16km square (1600 x 1600 pixels). The image has been reprojected from WGS 84 to British National Grid.

I have tried using `maintain_clipping_extent` and whilst it solves the partial pixels, unfortunately the pixels are resampled (which affects the spectral values I need for later analysis) and gives me 1599 rows and columns rather than the 1600 I need.

Comment: I have and whilst it solves the partial pixels, unfortunately the pixels are resampled (which affects the spectral values I need for later analysis) and gives me 1599 rows and columns rather than the 1600 i need

Comment: Could you clip out a small section of your raster at one of your polygon corners so your target point is within a complete pixel, convert them to polygons and then snap your clipping polygon to the corner of one of the them?